# WatchOS 2.0 wrist detection programmatically

Tags: ios

Is it possible to programmatically  detect apple watch position in 2.0?

I need to detect the following events:

- when watch is taken off;
- when watch is in proximity and worn on the wrist;
- when watch is in proximity and not worn on the wrist;
- when watch is not in proximity.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Only thing that you can do is access the accelerometer data or gyroscope data and based on that you can make some assumptions, on the watch state. Notice that your app is not called if it is in background, so you will get those only when your app comes to foreground. So, sadly you cannot do that.